# Are these two men named Thomas Holme the same man?

Tags: england

I am Japanese, but my great grandfather was an Englishman. But I can not identify him. I found a candidate for a great grandfather based on the record of Japan. His name is C. Z. Ede (Cecil Zohrab Ede). I learned C.Z.Ede at this site. I looked into C.Z.Ede. The time he lived in Kobe in Japan matches the time when my great-grandfather's brother was born. Also Jardine Matheson who worked for him agreed with the work of my great-grandmother's father. And he will leave Japan once, but he died in Shanghai in November 1901. My great-grandmother's family line is a Japanese samurai family line. Her older brother died young. She needed to inherit samurai 's family line. In February 1902 she became the owner of the house. From the timing of the death of C. Z. Ede and the timing of her inauguration, I think C. Z. Ede is my great-grandfather.

From this, the descendants of Zohrab put me in the Zohrab family. But I have no definitive proof that C.Z.Ede is my great-grandfather. So, I tested the DNA. So I focused on the Holme family of his mother's ancestor. C. Z. Ede's uncle is Ryle Holme. Ryle was Jordin Matheson's Kobe branch manager and was the boss of Ede.

I looked at the family line of DNA matched person at Ancestry.com. So I found Thomas Holme. His name is also in Family-Tree of Zohrab family. If these two are the same person, I will have a blood relationship with the Holme family and I will have found the evidence that C. Z. Ede was my great-grandfather. I want to check whether these two people are the same person. But in Japan there are not many things I can investigate. So I need your strength. By the way, I have learned that I've been investigating in Japan concerning Japanese history. Ryle Holme is greatly involved in the person who influenced Japan when it moved from the Edo period to the Meiji era.

For me it is a search for an ancestor, but many Japanese researchers have been interested in my research in the process I am investigating.

http://www.zorabfamily.co.za/ztbltre3.html

https://www.ancestry.co.uk/family-tree/person/tree/74942484/person/38484372184/story

Answer (score -1):

I felt that the following refs. would be of assistance to you and answer some of your questions.

British Birth certificate refs.
Cecil Zohrob Ede April-May-June 1863 Altringham, Cheshire, England, 8A, 167, 36

---

[Church of England Baptism](https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:NH66-7XX) refs. Bowdon, Cheshire, England

21 June 1863 Cecil Zohrob Ede son of Fredrick Charles Ede and Helen his wife was baptised.

---

[1871 Census](https://www.familysearch.org/search/search/record/results?count=20&query=%2Bgivenname%3A%22Cecil%20Zohrab%22~%20%2Bsurname%3AEde~) for the household, Bowdon, Cheshire, England

Household   Role    Sex Age Birthplace
Frederick C Ede Head    Male    46  Austria
Helen Ede   Wife    Female  36  Strand, Lancashire
Mathilda H Ede  Daughter    Female  10  Bondon, Cheshire
Cecil Z Ede Son Male    8   Bondon, Cheshire
Lorie G Ede Daughter    Female  6   Bondon, Cheshire
Edgar V Ede Son Male    1   Bondon, Cheshire
Sarah Rogerson  Servant Female  46  Norton, Cheshire
Jane A Crozier  Servant Female  25  Ireland, Ireland
Hannah Evans    Servant Female  27  Corver, Merionethshire
Winifred Evans  Servant Female  25  Corver, Merionethshire

---

British Newspaper archives

Cecil Zohrob Ede Obituary 27 Nov 1901

Comment: Thank you very much. I have all the records you have shown. But they did not give me evidence that C.Z.Ede was my great-grandfather. So I tried DNA testing. I tried that test at the famous Ancestry.com. However, I could only find Holme, the surname associated with C. Z. Ede's family line. I have found Olsen, Ipsen and Ipson there many with blooded surnames. It would be fine if these surnames could be confirmed with C.Z.Ede. I am searching for records but I can not find the relationship.

Comment: There are at least six siblings of Cecil Zohrob Ede, do you already have these or would you like a list of them?

Comment: Thank you very much.
I have that list. However, many of his siblings are gone young. I think that the youngest brother at the bottom moved to Australia. I found him who seemed to be his descendant in Face Book and contacted him. I intended to ask him for a DNA test. Because if he does a DNA test, my question will be solved. But he did not reply.